# Where are the Xcode 'behaviors' stored?

Tags: xcode, behavior

I had to start fresh with Xcode and I'm going crazy having to configure all just as I like. I have it installed in other computer and I'd like to copy the "behaviors" from there. Where are they stored?

EDIT: I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 (and I want to migrate from the same version)

Comment: In Xcode preferences file ?

Comment: Which version did you use before and what is the new version? Where would you click to get to behaviors in your previous version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in the Xcode preferences file located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`.

The key `Xcode.AlertEvents` (previously named `Xcode.CustomAlertEvents`) contains all the defined custom behaviors.